# CakePHP 1.3 DebugKit - setting debug level for specific user

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to set the debug level for a specific user to 2. If I use the app_controller.php for that DebugKit does not show up, only if I set it in the core.php but I only want to do it for one specific loggedin user.

What is the best way to do that?

---

**Update:**
This is what I did in the beforeFilter function in app_controller.php (which didn't work):

```
if($this->Auth->user('id') == 1)
        Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you trying to do this?

Normally I do it in `beforeFilter` in `AppController` and works fine.

```
if (...) {
    Configure::write('debug', 2);
}
```

**Update**

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->Auth->user('id') == 1) {
        Configure::write('debug', 2);
        $this->components[] = 'DebugKit.Toolbar';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what I did and it works for the normal CakePHP debugging, but DebugKit doesn't show up, only if I change the value in core.php (but I dont want that all users can see this).

Comment: Ok! Since `DebugKit` is a component, you can try to attach and detach as needed. Check my update.

Comment: Ah I see. But in this case I would have to set debug to 2 in core.php and everybody would see it. Is there a way to set debug in bootstrap.php only for a specific user?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to set debug to 2 in core.php. Since you said that defining it in app_controller.php works, can not set the debug level and attach the component both in `beforeFilter`?

Comment: oh sorry this is what I meant: If I want the standard CakePHP debugging, setting it to 2 in app_controller.php works. But I want to use DebugKit. Setting debug to 2 in app_controller.php doesn't make DebugKit appear. If I set it in core.php DebugKit does appear (that's why I think this is the reason why its not working).

Comment: Ok, I suggested doing both at the same time, see my updated answer.